# Class function that takes min or max value of array of type *this

Tags: c++, arrays, class

suppose I have a class called particle:

```
class particle {
public:
    void set_values(double x, double y) {
        x_val = x;
        y_val = y;
    }
    double X() { return x_val; }
    double Y() { return y_val; }
private:
    x_val, y_val;
};
```

Now suppose I have an array of type particle with 3 objects particle inside:

```
int main(){
    particle p1;
    particle p2;
    particle p3;
    p1.set_values(3,1);
    p2.set_values(2,4);
    p3.set_values(1,5);
    part array_part[3] = {p1, p2, p3};
    return 0;
}
```

Now my question:
how can I create a function within the class, that takes array_part and returns the maximum or minimum value of the X() or Y() values of it?
Of course I could do this outside the class by just filling a new array with e.g. all the X() values and use the c++ function min_element. This code would look like this for the min value:

```
double array_x[3] = {p1.X(), p2.X(), p3.X()};
double X_min =  *min_element(array_x, array_x
    + sizeof(array_x)/sizeof(*array_x));
```

X_min would now be = 1.
But how inside the class without having to write to much in the main? I really have no idea how to start.

Comment: Use std::minmax_element with lambdas

Comment: Your class does not hold the array, so you cannot use the `this` pointer - you could write a `static` helper function which takes the array as parameter and finds the minimum value. Also you should prefer `std::vector` or `std::array` over raw arrays

Comment: What is `part` in the `main` function? The line before `return` statement. I think is should be `particle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not following the best Software Engineering practice, but if you want something by this way, you can do as follow

```
class Particle {
public:
    void set_values(double x, double y) {
        x_val = x;
        y_val = y;
    }
    double X() { return x_val; }
    double Y() { return y_val; }

    // If you need minimun Y, change the X for Y on the function.
    double get_min_x(Particle* particles, int n){
        double minimun = particles[0].X();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(particles[i].X() < minimun){
                minimun = particles[i].X();
            }
        }
        return minimun;
    }
private:
    double x_val, y_val;
};
```

Considering `Particle array_part[3] = {p1, p2, p3};` you can do that

```
p1.get_min_x(array_part, 3)
```

when you are modeling a class, think about: What does a particle know? What does a particle do? Does a particle know which particle has the smallest x or y? I think not!

Comment: Why do you convert from double to float?

Comment: @mistapink I forgot it was double, because I ever use float for coordinates.